# For Each in Mysql

Tags: mysql, for-loop, foreach

I have a table that has the following field:

```
id | listrate | retailrate
1  |    .10   |   .12
```

Right now the retail rate is 12%. I needed a mysql query that will update all the retail rate to 40% basically a query that say for each record listrate * 1.4. I need your help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table is named `tableName`, if you need to set the `retailrate` to 40%, the SQL query would be:

```
UPDATE tableName SET retailrate = .40
```

If you need to increase the `retailrate` **by** 40% :

```
UPDATE tableName SET retailrate = retailrate * 1.4
```